# Forwarding port not working OS X Lion Server

Tags: tomcat, osx-lion, firewall, portforwarding

I am trying to forward port 80 to 8484

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8484 tcp from any to any 80 in
```

This works on my local machine (OS X 10.6), but not on my server OS X 7.

Whenever I attempt to connect to any URL after adding the rule I get 
Not Found

The requested URL /login.htm was not found on this server.

This is the output of ipfw show after adding the rule:

```
00100 0 0 fwd 127.0.0.1,8484 tcp from any to any dst-port 80 in
01000 0 0 allow ip from any to any via lo0
01010 0 0 deny ip from any to 127.0.0.0/8
01020 0 0 deny ip from 224.0.0.0/4 to any in
01030 0 0 deny tcp from any to 224.0.0.0/4 in
12300 0 0 allow tcp from any to any established
12301 0 0 allow tcp from any to any out
12302 0 0 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 22
12302 0 0 allow udp from any to any dst-port 22
12303 0 0 allow udp from any to any dst-port 68
12304 0 0 allow udp from any to any out keep-state
12305 0 0 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 53 out keep-state
12305 0 0 allow udp from any to any dst-port 53 out keep-state
12306 0 0 allow udp from any to any in frag
12307 0 0 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 311
12308 0 0 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 625
12309 0 0 allow icmp from any to any icmptypes 8
12310 0 0 allow icmp from any to any icmptypes 0
12311 0 0 allow igmp from any to any
65534 0 0 deny ip from any to any
65535 0 0 allow ip from any to any
```

I cannot tell if forwarding is actually working when the rule is added. Is there any way to test this? Also, what could be blocking the forwarding rule from being recognized.

I have tried flushing all the rules and adding in the one rule

```
00100 0 0 fwd 127.0.0.1,8484 tcp from any to any dst-port 80 in
```

but this has no effect either.

Comment: the command serveradmin start ipfilter worked to start port forwarding. But I cannot access the site at the old port anymore (only at port 80) I would also like the website to be accessible at the port so either serveraddresss/ or serveraddress:8484/ what set of rules should I have to allow this?

Comment: Sounds like a question more appropriate for serverfault.